# Spring Batch Admin Config Throw ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-batch-admin

I am unable to configure Spring Batch Admin 1.3.0
I have overridden the data source defaults but I keep getting all kinds of errors.
The last one has to do with `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.42]
        ... 35 more
Sep 30, 2014 5:45:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

I have included Spring Messaging 4.0 jar in the pom..

Comment: Can you add the pom? Or any of your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues using Spring Batch Admin 1.3.0 with Spring 4.1.4 . Several of the classes have had their names changed or have been moved to different packages.  Also, a couple of the previously deprecated "SimpleXxx" classes have been dropped (SimpleJdbcTemplate, for example).  The resolution is to use the current classes and packages, and to lose the "simple" from a couple of class names.

I finally resolved all of my issues with spring-batch-admin by downloading the current 1.3.1.RELEASE source from github and building it without any modifications.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `spring-integration-core` jar. Please check and try again.